# How to set default storage Account for Azure RM Subscription

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account

I am trying to set Azure Rm Subscription (`Get-AzureRMSubscription`) CurrentStorageAccount to a particular arm storage account (`Get-AzureRmStorageAccount`) and I am not able to find a cmdlet that does that.

With regular old azure cmdlets I am able to do following to set CurrentStorageAccount as

```
$subscription = Get-AzureSubscription
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscription.SubscriptionName -CurrentStorageAccountName "somestorageaccount"

Get-AzureSubscription | select *
```

This set's it. But I cannot do this inside arm cmdlets.

Another thing that is confusing is that I am using the same subscription eg. Visual Studio Enterprise. And using both arm and regular cmdlets get-azuresubscription I get the same subscription but why is one showing -CurrentStorageAccount and another subscription not showing -CurrentStorageAccount.

Answer (score 11):

To set the **default RM subscription** for the current session in PowerShell use

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName "MyFavSubscription" | Select-AzureRmSubscription
```

and to set the **default RM storage context** for the current session

```
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount –ResourceGroupName "MyFavResourceGroup" `
                                 –StorageAccountName "MyFavStorageAccountName"
```

Comment: How do you know if piping the result to Select-AzureRMSubscription is setting the "default" versus the "current" subscription?  I couldn't find the answer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/select-azuresubscription?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

Comment: By the looks of it, if you don't specify -default or -current than both are set. If you only want to set one or other then add the flag.

Comment: @Mitul If this is the answer to your question please mark it as such

Answer (score 2):

First, you must set your default subscription.

```
$SubscriptionName = "MyDefaultSubscription"
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName –Default
```

In other cases, you can set your default subscription location.

```
# For example, South Central US
$Location = "South Central US"
```

Then get your storage account name/s

```
$StorageAccountName = (Get-AzureStorageAccount)[0].label
```

Notice the number zero? It indicates the numbering of your storage. The numbering starts with 0. If you use the command [Get-AzureStorageAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495134.aspx), it will list all of your (classic) storage accounts. For that you can choose your desired storage.

Then lastly, set your default storage account.

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName -CurrentStorageAccountName $StorageAccountName
```

Answer (score 0):

That commandlet is called [Set-AzureRMCurrentStorageAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607147.aspx).

Comment: So that command doesn't work. I see currentstorageaccount as blank when I execute Get-AzureRmSubscription  | select *

Comment: It sets on the context so if I do Get-AzureRMContext it give me the CurrentStorageAccount

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you said, `set-azureRmCurrentStorageAccount -context $Ctx` will set your default Storage account to context. I also can't find any articles to get out explanation on this. I think you can try to use [Azure CLI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-azure-cli/) to set your default Azure storage account in environment variables.